# CollectionViewIndexPathForPoint returns nil at cell breaks

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

The lldb printouts below show `indexPathForItemAtPoint:` returning nil on cell divisions. Why is this?

```
(lldb) po [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 83)]
<NSIndexPath: 0x17824540> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}

(lldb) po [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 84)]
 nil
(lldb) po [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 85)]
<NSIndexPath: 0x17824500> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}

(lldb) po [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 169)]
<NSIndexPath: 0x17824500> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}

(lldb) po [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 170)]
 nil
(lldb) po [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 171)]
<NSIndexPath: 0x17824510> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}
```

Comment: What actually you are trying to do? Why you are expecting indexPath on each and every point? 170 might be the position between two cells.

Comment: As this is part of the UICollectionView-implementation, which we cannot see and the source is not available, nobody, except an Apple developer with access to the code, can answer that question.

I would assume, that the implementation asks its layout if the point is contained by a frame of a cell and eventually returns the cell's indexPath. In-between there is no cell, so nil is returned.

I found this question on my search for a method to find the indexPath of the cell, whose frame is closest to a given point. Just for resolving the issue of dragging something between cells or an empty part.